# text-overflow: ellipsis in li without using overflow: hidden

Tags: css

I have `<li>` tag which contains some text with unknown length (changable by user). So I'm trying to set ellipsis to that `<li>` but with no luck. I can't set `overflow: hidden` because I made custom tooltip which is inside this `<li>` so if `overflow: hidden` is set, my tooltip is not visible. This is what I tried:

```
<ul>
<li class="title">Some very long text</li>
<li> ... </li>
</ul>

ul {
    list-style: none;
    min-width: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.title {
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 140px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;  
}
```

Comment: You can not have `text-overflow` without actually limiting the overflow. You will have to place the text inside your LI into an additional element.

Comment: Thanks for advice, I put paragraph inside li and applied text-overflow, now it works

Answer (score 0):

add this style to your 'title' class

```
.title {
  ...
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on how your CSS style has fixed OP's problem or why you used it.

Answer (score -2):

Use absolute positioning. Some small changes to your mark-up.

Here is the **FIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/n9G7y/

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Some very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text very long text</span>

        <span class="tip">tip for this item extends beyond end of ellipsis</span>

    </li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
 ul {
    list-style: none;
    min-width: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-table;
    margin-right: 5px;
    overflow: visible;
}
li {
    position: relative;
}
.title {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 140px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.tip {
    display: none;
}

li:hover .tip {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 300px;
}
```